# Error PHP Twitter share

Tags: php, button, twitter, share

I have a problem with this code:

```
<?php echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="User" data-size="large">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>'; ?>
```

I get the error:

Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or`';''

Comment: HTML/PHP/JS - why are you doing all this code injection?

Comment: To change from one php file different sections of a web.                         <?php
require_once("sidebar.php");
?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to escape all of the single quotes in that string or don't use PHP to output that code (recommended):

```
<?php 
//some php code
?>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="User" data-size="large">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?''http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
<?php
// more PHP code
?>
```

Escaped quotes:

```
<?php echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="User" data-size="large">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?\'http\':\'https\';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+\'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, \'script\', \'twitter-wjs\');</script>'; ?>
```